# TTF fonts are being converted to image in CPU or GPU?

Tags: gpu, fonts, ttf, cpu

Once I use a TTF font, when they are being converted to images to be rendered? Does CPU or GPU do the conversion? How heavy is that operation?

Comment: what engine? what library? what language?

Comment: I use cocos2d-x, but it is important? Isn't there a common way to do that? Sorry if my question is too dummy. I am a noob in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many game engines you would create a [texture map](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/04/26/bitmap-fonts-in-xna.aspx) for your fonts, rendering the TTF font into a character sheet that is used in the game itself, but it is quite possible to [convert the TTF bezier curves into geometry](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/loopblinn05.pdf) that can be rendered directly on the GPU in a very efficient way.

In the end, the performance difference is minimal and unless you are planning on rendering your entire game with text (like in the scene towards the end of the first [Matrix film](https://youtu.be/xsYierkdxaI?t=1m43s)) you won't be able to tell the difference in a real game.

Comment: "...you won't be able to tell the difference in a real game." if it is converted to a texture in CPU or GPU you mean?

Comment: @Narek Yes exactly, you won't be drawing enough text to be able to tell the difference in speed between the two versions. It's worth mentioning as well that both versions wind up having geometry rendering, the texturemap version using simple texture lookup where the gpu version uses a specialized (but fast) shader. The texture version tends to build the texture at compile time as well, making the difference even smaller.